# Did people analyze dynamics of very simple LSTMs?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, long-short-term-memory

I wonder if researchers tried to understand how LSTMs work by analyzing the dynamics of simple LSTM (e.g. with 2 units)? For example, how the hidden state evolves depending on the properties of weight matrices.

It seems like a very natural thing to try (especially because it is easy to draw hidden states with 2 units on a 2D plane). However, I haven't found any papers that would play with such a toy example.

Are there such papers at all?

Or with such a simple example, it is impossible to get some understanding because of its over-simplicity? (which I doubt because even logistic maps generate very complicated behavior)

Comment: Yes they have: https://youtu.be/jvj4WefJ0S0?list=PLiJYYsK6pD-nVcROKw2YDOVaNMjST5YyL&t=1711